# Resetting ViewModels created by Caliburn Micro

Tags: mvvm, windows-store-apps, caliburn.micro

I am trying to implement Logout functionality in a Windows Store app that I am working on which is using Caliburn Micro.

The challenge that I am having is that if a user logs out, and then logs in again as another user, the ViewModels instantiated at app launch still exists in memory and have references to old models. Hence, Views are being displayed with stale data of the first user.

To better explain myself:

```
public class LoginViewModel : Screen
{        
    private User _model;

    // Property gets initialised only on instantiation of ViewModel class
    public User Model
    {
        get { return _model; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _model)) return;
            _model = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Model);
        }
    }

    // ViewModel constructor - instantiated once only by Caliburn on startup
    public LoginHeaderViewModel(IAuthService authService)
    {
        Model = _authService.User;
    }
}
```

When my app first launches, Caliburn will automatically instantiate `LoginViewModel` and run its constructor, which in turn fetches the current logged in user. After a user is logged out, and another user logs in, `LoginViewModel` is not instantiated again at runtime because it already exists. The `Model` property is not re-evaluated and hence the associated View is not told to refresh itself.

I tried re-creating Caliburn's `WinRTContainer` on logout but the application started behaving funny. I was suspicious of going down this approach anyway so didn't look too much into it just yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I resolved my initial problem (and there are many ways to do so) is using Caliburn event aggregation.

I first start off by creating an event:

```
public class LoginEvent
{
    public bool IsloggedIn { get; set; }

    public LoginEvent(bool isloggedIn)
    {
        IsloggedIn = isloggedIn;
    }
}
```

When a user logs in, I make sure that I publish an instance of the login event:

```
public LoginViewModel(IEventAggregator events)
{
    _events = events;
}

public async void SignIn()
{
    // Do login logic ...
    _events.Publish(new LoginEvent(true));
}
```

In the ViewModel that needs to rest itself whenever a new user logs in, ensure that I subscribe to the `LoginEvent` to reinitialise my models when it is triggered. A ViewModel listening to events **must** implement the `IHandle<T>` interface.

```
public class DependentViewModel : IHandle<LoginEvent>
{
    public DependentViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
        InitialiseViewModel();
    }

    public async void InitialiseViewModel()
    {
        // Initialise all your model objects here...
    }

    public async void Handle(LoginEvent ev)
    {
        if (ev.IsloggedIn)
        {
            InitialiseViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What `Lifestyle` do your `ViewModel` objects have?

There are also `override` methods such as `OnDeactivate` which you could use to clean up user specific settings, [take a look here](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens,%20Conductors%20and%20Composition&referringTitle=Documentation) specifically at the **screens** section for methods that you can `override`.

Comment: `OnDeactivate` will allow me to clear any models that I have. However, i need to reset or re-initialize my models. I guess this can be done in `OnActivate`